# Sending emails with EmailMessage does not work when I deploy my application

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application with django. When I send emails locally with EmailMessage it works, but after deployment on heroku it doesn't work anymore. Here is the code in views.py

```
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string

    message = render_to_string("elec_meter/activate_email.html",
                  {
                   "user": user, "domaine": request.META['HTTP_HOST'],
                   "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id)),
                   "token": default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                   "password": password,"matricule": agent.matricule
                  }
              )
    email_to_send = EmailMessage("Activation du compte", message, to=[email])
    email_to_send.send()
```

in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my_email"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

I need help please

Comment: What's the error saying ?

Comment: There are some things to be done on the Gmail account to make this work : https://dev.to/abderrahmanemustapha/how-to-send-email-with-django-and-gmail-in-production-the-right-way-24ab

Comment: It doesn't give me an error but it works perfectly locally.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how it's working on Heroku, you don't have any error log which could point out where to look ?

Comment: You could try `send(fail_silently=False)` to catch the problem

Comment: I don't see anything in the heroku logs